# Using 1 Controller For Multiple Database Tables

Tags: c#, mysql, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi, http-get

My database contains multiple tables and I have 1 controller. I want to use that controller to perform HTTP action methods like get, put, delete etc for each table in this 1 controller. Is this possible to do? Currently I have a separate controller for each table but each time I run my WebAPI I have to change the controller that opens up in the Startup file. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: It possible, but not recommended. You should seperate your api actions into multiple controllers. Many people do the seperation by res-resource (kind of like you said, by database table). Now what I am curious is, why do you need to change something so that you can access a diffrent controller. To answer this question, we would need to see some code of your `Statup.cs`

Comment: Besides, as far as your current approach is concerned, you don't need to change the startup file every time you run a different controller in webapi. The startup file sets `the default page` for running the project. You can `manually change the url to run the controller` you want to test, instead of taking the modified path in the startup file every time.